# How to set up ssh connection (acessible over internet, not LAN) using MTS MBLaze modem?

Tags: ssh, vpn, tunnel

I have a MTS MBlaze USB dongle, with which I can connect to the internet. The question is, how do I set up a ssh connection accessible over the internet so that any one can connect to my PC through that (using valid username/password provided by me of course) ? If not possible, what do I need to make this possible ?

I'm using ubuntu 10.04 - but can upgrade if absolutely required.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## install ssh

First things first. You need ssh installed. Not just the client, the server too. Find out:

```
$ which ssh
/usr/bin/ssh
$ which sshd
/usr/sbin/sshd
```

If `which` can't find them, you need to install: `sudo apt-get install ssh sshd`.

The install process should set up everything, but just in case, make sure the ssh port (22), is open (if ufw is disabled, consider enabling it): `sudo ufw allow 22/tcp`

## what is your address

Type `ip addr | grep inet` to get your ip address. If it starts with `192.168.`, `172.16.` up to `172.31.`, or `10.`, you have a local (aka private) ip address. Otherwise it is public (eg 74.125.224.51). If it is public, you have it easy. Anyone can try and connect with a command like `ssh bob@74.125.224.51`.

If you are stuck with a local IP address, you need to configure your router to forward port 22 to your computer. Then you can go to a site like http://whatismyip.org/ to get your public ip address, and anyone who has it can try and connect with a command like `ssh bob@74.125.224.51`.

## get a permanent address

Sign up with http://dyndns.com/ for their free Host Services to link a dyndns name to your ip address. I'm assuming here that you have not bought a static ip address from your ISP.

Comment: Pretty much nailed it :)

Comment: Is `openssh-server` significantly different from `sshd`?

Comment: @hexafraction `openssh-server` provides an implementation of `sshd`. it's well-respected, to say the least.

Comment: "If you are stuck with a local IP address, you need to configure your router to forward port 22 to your computer". How to perform the port forwarding ?

Comment: @cosmicraga very much depends on your router. if yours is a popular model, you may be able to ask a question on one of these StackExchange sites